# Trying to swap to components to the right position

Tags: c#, winforms, location

I am struggling to swap two components in c#, one button (Windows Form) is bigger than the other which I assume is the cause of the problem.

This is what it looks like in the beginning:

[image]

This is what the end result should be:

[image]

However with my code the results end up doing the following:

[image]

My code:

```
 tempC.Location = btnBlockSix.Location; //tempC is a dynamic button (temporarily used to save values), btnBlockSix is also a button (the big one).
 btnBlockSix.Location = send.Location; //send is a button (the small one) (the empty button)
 send.Location = tempC.Location;
```

Comment: There isn't enough information here to answer your question.  Show all the relevant code.  3 assignments called "Location" does not tell us anything useful.

Comment: I have updated the answer with more information as to regarding which variable is referring to which button, and the button types which is a standard Windows Form Button. Would that be suffice?

Comment: You should consider working with visibility or colors instead of moving the location of controls. Cant you simply change the greeen to transparent on the first button and the other way around on the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I wrong or is one of you buttons bigger than the other? Because then u have to to do something like this:

```
     tempC.Location = btnBlockSix.Location; //tempC is a button.

     btnBlockSix.Location = send.Location; //send is a button (the empty button)[enter image description here][1]

     send.Location = tempC.Location.Y - (btnBlockSix.height - send.Location.height);
```

Or something like this.
Your post description of the Buttons ist pretty unclear

Comment: Yes apologies my button is bigger than the other one, your code gives me the error "Point does not contain a definition for height".

Comment: Since i do not now what kind of button youre using..
My Code was meant to give you the idea. You have to move the green button up by it height minus the height of the small button

Comment: It is a normal Windows Form button that I dragged and dropped from the toolbox